# c++ Program Not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am a newbie in c++
I am trying to make a program which counts no of digits in an input
Here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int i, n, r, t,  large;
float f;
int main() {
    do {
        using namespace  std;
        cout<<"Enter a Number"<<endl;
        cin>>n;

        do {
            f=n/10;
            i=0;
            t=i + 1;
        } while (f > 1);

        cout<<"No of Digits = ";
        cout<<t<<endl;

        cout<<"Do u wish to continue"<<endl;
        cin>>r;
    }
    while (r!='y');
}
```

This works Well if i add a single digit No
This is the output when i add single digit No

[image: output for single digit no]

But when i add more than 1 digit no 
it stucks and doesn't moves ahead
here is the output when i add more that 1 no

[image: Output for more than 1 digit no]

Can someone please help me

Comment: Those globals have no point. You should keep variable declarations in the innermost scope possible and as close to first use as possible.

Comment: I don't think `f` needs to be a `float`. It should be an `int` like the other variables.

Comment: You won't be penalized for giving your variables longer (and more descriptive) names.

Comment: There's no need to paste images which contain only text output. Post the text output instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the program variable `f` should be an int.

The loop should be as follows,

```
f=n;
i=0;

do {
    f=f/10;
    i++;
}while(f > 0);

cout<<"\nNumber of Digits : "<<i;
```

Comment: Works if `f` is an integral type (like `int`).

Comment: Sorry my mistake.. What I wanted to say was that "f should be an int"

Comment: @deepu   U need to add f>1 in order to make it work or else it is never ending process as it will continue till infinity .for example like 0.000000000000002344

Answer (score 4):

You have an infinite loop

```
do {
    f=n/10;
    i=0;
    t=i + 1;
} while (f > 1);
```

If n is 2 digits, then you keep reassigning the same values.  I think you intended to change the first line

```
f = n; // new line
t = 0; // moved line
do {
    f = f / 10; // changed line
    t = t + 1;  // changed line
} while (f >= 1);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Updated to account for your catch!

Comment: I think it works with the float (although it wasn't neeed), but you're right, I had to change it to `>=`  If I use 100, we go through the loop three times with f ending the loop at 10, 1.0, 0.1.   If I use 101, we go through the loop with f ending the loop at 10.1, 1.01, 0.101.

Comment: I'm not entirely confident this isn't prone to rounding errors; `==` on floating point types is not a good idea. And integer division is most probably going to be faster anyway.